# how to remove a blacklisted module linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, boot, drivers, nvidia

I recently updated my nvidia drivere through update manager and when I did that all my monitors went blank, I waited about 20 minutes and they stayed blank so i restarted and now I get the error: "failed to start detect the deal with any system changes", "failed to start light display manager".

I ran /etc/modprobe.d in root mode through recovery mode and saw that nvidia drivers were blacklisted.

I just switched to linux about a couple weeks ago so I am still very new and would apreaciate any help.